# how to use multithread in cython correctly?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, cython

I have a code that contains 2 nested for loop and want to run it with multithreading and see if it runs faster? Here is my code :

```
import cython
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cpdef int test_speed(unsigned char[:, :] Rint, unsigned char[:, :] Gint, unsigned char[:, :] Bint, unsigned char[:, :] table):
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] R_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype="uint8")
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] B_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype="uint8")
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] G_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype="uint8")
    cdef int i, j
    for i in range(1024):
           for j in range(1024):
               # r = np.round(Rint[i,j])
               R_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Rint[i,j]]
               # s = np.round(Gint[i,j])
               G_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Gint[i,j]]
               # t = np.round(Bint[i,j])
               B_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Bint[i,j]]
    return 1
```

I tried this code and didn't notice any speed up also checked process threads and only 1 thread was busy at 12-14% so is that working or i did anything wrong?

```
import cython
import numpy as np
from cython.parallel import prange


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cpdef int test_speed(unsigned char[:, :] Rint, unsigned char[:, :] Gint, unsigned char[:, :] Bint, unsigned char[:, :] table):
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] R_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] B_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')
    cdef unsigned char[:, :] G_ch_new=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')

    cdef int i, j

    for i in prange(1024, nogil=True):
           for j in range(1024):
               # r = np.round(Rint[i,j])
               R_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Rint[i,j]]
               # s = np.round(Gint[i,j])
               G_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Gint[i,j]]
               # t = np.round(Bint[i,j])
               B_ch_new[i,j]=table[0, Bint[i,j]]
    return 1
```

this is how I test speed :

```
import time

import numpy as np
from testspeed1 import test_speed
table=np.zeros((1, 256), dtype='uint8')
Rint=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')
Gint=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')
Bint=np.zeros((1024, 1024), dtype='uint8')

for i in range(1024):
    for j in range(1024):
        Rint[i, j] = np.random.randint(0, 255)
        Gint[i, j] = np.random.randint(0, 255)
        Bint[i, j] = np.random.randint(0, 255)

for i in range(256):
    table[0, i] = np.random.randint(0, 255)

start = time.time()
result = test_speed(Rint, Gint, Bint, table)
end = time.time()
print('duration : ', str(end - start))
```

***Update :
i use this setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup

import numpy
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("testspeed1",
              ["testspeed1.pyx"],
              extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],

              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
              )
]

setup(
    name="testspeed1",
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules),
    include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

and run with this command :
`python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Comment: note that if you are going to benchmark the code consider changing `np.zeros` with `np.empty`.

Comment: I think you missed the most important point: how the code is compiled and run? Besides, compilers are free to completely optimize out your code (ie. not execute it) since it does not have any visible side effect: nothing is returned. Clang usually does such optimization.

Comment: I compile with easycython package and ran using the last code block I added after edit

Comment: I do know this `easycython` package but I think it does not provide the correct flags so to enable parallelism. AFAIK, You need to tell to the compiler to use OpenMP typically using the `-fopenmp` flag (both the link and the build). It looks like this simple package does not supports that. Consider using the standard common way to build Cython scripts.

Comment: @JérômeRichard i used standard compile way and no changes happened in run, cpu is at 20% utilization, isn't it supposed to run through all cores and more utilization?

Comment: You should not use the default parameter. OpenMP needs to be manually enabled. Otherwise, the parallelism is disabled. I guess you use a 6 core processor so 20% is about to be 1 core used (+ some small work on others).

Comment: I added setup.py and the run command in question, is there anything missing? my cpu has 8 logical cores

Comment: You're missing `extra_link_args`. It's still possible the compiler is eliminating the entire loop though, because it does nothing that's externally visible (probably not - I suspect it struggles to track the lifetime of Numpy arrays - but it might)

Comment: I added it first but it showed warning with msg unrecognized link option fopenmp so I removed it, I'm working on windows and using visual build tools, does that limit and I have to try in linux?

Comment: Msvc uses slightly different compiler flags but it should work

Comment: i tried with the flag you told but it throws warning and skips that and it didn't change anything to run on more than 1 core

Comment: MSVC uses a 20 years old version of OpenMP which is now completely obsolete and not very efficient (this is a shame). There is a non-default implementation using IOMP (LLVM). It is considered quite experimental so far. The flags for OpenMP with MSVC is `/openmp`, not `-fopenmp`. You need to use `/openmp:llvm` for the LLVM runtime. Alternatively, you can use GNU/LLVM compilers. This may also generate a faster sequential code (MSVC often generate a code that is not as good as other mainstream compiler, especially for vectorization).

Answer (score 0):

Seems OpenMP is not working because the extra_link_args='-fopenmp' is not set. However, this will give a warning in Windows. In general, I would add this in the setup file to avoid it:

```
if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
     openmp_arg = '-openmp'
     opt_compiler = '/O2'
else:
     openmp_arg = '-fopenmp'
     opt_compiler = '-O3'

ext_modules = [Extension("name",
                     ["source to pyx"],
                     extra_compile_args=[openmp_arg, opt_compiler],
                     extra_link_args=[openmp_arg] if '-f' in openmp_arg else [])]
```

Cheers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).